# For Loop in Postman not Working as Expected

Tags: for-loop, postman, postman-collection-runner

I am trying to use Postman Runner and run through a JSON data file and get every record back from the data file in the console.

Currently I am only getting the first line back.

My JSON data file looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "line1": "13579",
    "line2": "2468",
    "line3": "1234",
    "line4": "5678",
  },
  {
    "line1": "13468",
    "line2": "2425",
    "line3": "12578",
    "line4": "567343",
  }
]
```

My code that I have tried is:

```js
var res = JSON.parse(responseBody);

for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
  console.log("actual data: " + i + " = " + data[i].line1);

    // tests start
    pm.test("iteration: " + i + " = " + "expected line1 = " + data.line1 + " | Actual line1 = " + res[i].line1 , function () {
        pm.expect(res[i].line1).to.equal(data[i].line1);
    });
}
```

However, this prints out an error in the console:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'line1' of undefined"
```

If I change this to `console.log("actual data: " + i + " = " + data.line1);`, it then writes out:

```
actual data: 0 = 13579
actual data: 1 = 13579
actual data: 2 = 13579
```

[![Postman runner][1]][1]

1. Am I using the for loop correctly?
2. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
I forgot to add what my `res` returns when I send the URL:

```json
[
  {
    "line1": "13579",
    "line2": "2468",
    "line3": "1234",
    "line4": "5678"
  },
  {
    "line1": "13468",
    "line2": "2425",
    "line3": "12578",
    "line4": "567343"
  },
  {
    "line1": "1test8",
    "line2": "24te25",
    "line3": "125st78",
    "line4": "567test343"
  }
]
```

Comment: I have been trying all sorts of different methods to get this to work. I have reverted to not use a for loop - even though I really need the loop. but still not getting the records as I want (see question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague helped me on this.

The resolution is to use `res[pm.info.iteration].line1`.

The full test would be:

```js
    // start tests
    pm.test("expected line1 = " + (data["line1"]) + " | Actual line1 = " + (res[pm.info.iteration].line1), function () {
        pm.expect(res[pm.info.iteration].line1).to.equal(data["line1"]);
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

The way to use data file is data["columnname"] it doesn't have multiple rows. It doesn't give the entire data object but only the data for current iteration so . you cannot use data object to iterate through all the content in the csv

Try printing :

```
console.log( JSON.stringify(data))
```

if you want to use csv , then store it as an environemnt variable and then use it :

example :

https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/8296678/TzeUp9Me

use this public collection

Comment: Thank you, however, I am still struggling as using `console.log( JSON.stringify(data))`, this prints out the whole json output multiple times (and it is not different data - it is the same line over and over again for the duration of `res.length`. I have a feeling that as my array has no name; I am going to struggle to reference it.

Comment: yes because for that particular iteration data will have only the first row value

Comment: Ok I now have my `data.line1` working, but my `res.line1` is now broken. Sorry, forgot to mention that I have tried `res[i].line1` and tried `res.line1`. Both of these are not working properly. If I change the for loop to be `i=0;i<1;i++` then `res[i].line1` is duplicated 4 times, then the next block shows a different value. But my `data["line1"]` works fine all the way down.

Comment: With no `for` loop and using `console.log("data: " + JSON.stringify(data["line1"]) + " to res: " + res.line1);` - this then returns the correct value for `data`; however, it returns `undefined` for `res`.

Comment: res returns a list you have to mention was you have to select. do you only have one request in your collection ? the best way is to store the csv as environment variable

Comment: I have 1 request in my collection that uses this data file. My code is: `var res = JSON.parse(responseBody);   for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    console.log("data: " + JSON.stringify(data["line1"]) + " to res: " + res[i].line1);
}` This returns `data: "13579" to res: 13579` as the first line. The second line is then: `data: "13579" to res: 2468`, and so on. Which shows `data` is the same, until iteration 2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why you try to get `line1` from `data`? Your parsed JSON is in `res` variable.

```js
var res = JSON.parse(responseBody);

for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
  console.log("actual data: " + i + " = " + res[i].line1);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I meant to add the `pm.test` into my question. Will edit now.

Comment: but where is that ```data``` variable?

Comment: the `data` variable is used by Postman to call the data file attached in the runner.

Comment: I did, it is the JSON file at the top of my question. I will add a screenshot, but will have to blank the file name, etc. for privacy reasons.

Comment: Hi tmsbrndz, just read up about the data variable, and this is what I found: "Data variables come from external CSV and JSON files to define data sets that you can use while collections are running through Newman or the Collection Runner." - https://www.javatpoint.com/variables-in-postman