# For Loop Duplicating Results in Postman Data files - Using Collection Runner

Tags: for-loop, postman, postman-collection-runner

This is in relation to my previous question: [For Loop in Postman not Working as Expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67982802/for-loop-in-postman-not-working-as-expected).

This is my test data (saved as `numbers.json` ):

```json
[
  {
    "numbers": 1422.39
  },
  {
    "numbers": 429.01
  }
]
```

> I run this test in the Postman Runner.

My code is:

```js
const jsonData = pm.response.json();
for (let i=0; i < jsonData.length; i++)
{
    console.log("Response " + [i] + " data = " + data["numbers"]);
}
```

The output looks like this:

[image: Output results]

And if I use the code:

```js
console.log("Response " + [i] + " data = " + data[i].numbers);
```

Then I will get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'numbers' of undefined
```

My `responseBody` is (same as the data file - it is a copy, so that the numbers will match):

```json
[
  {
    "numbers": 1422.39
  },
  {
    "numbers": 429.01
  }
]
```

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to do here. Each object is an iteration and you will only see that data, you don't see all the data in the file on each iteration.

Comment: Yeah so I am only wanting the first object's "numbers" data to be returned per iteration. i.e. `data[0].numbers` would return `1422.39` and then `data[1].numbers` would return `429.01`. But it is not doing that :( It fails when I try that

Comment: How is it going to even do that? `pm.iterationData.get('numbers')` would get the `numbers` property in that **first** datafile object, it doesn't loop through the datafile, it knows nothing about the rest of the file. On the second iteration, it would get the `numbers` property from the **second** object in the file. This doesn't work `data[0].numbers` because it's a single object and not an array.

Comment: Thanks @DannyDainton, but `data[0].numbers` doesn't work. `pm.iterationData.get(`numbers`)` returns the data, same as `data["numbers"]`

Comment: outside of an array, then my tests all pass, but because the jsonData (responseBody) is in an array; I am struggling.

Comment: I didn't say that it worked :D You're using the older syntax and I would recommend using the `pm.*` API in the sandbox.

Comment: You haven't shown what the response body is in the question, you have shown what the datafile is. I don't even know what you're actually trying to loop through. :D

Comment: Sorry @DannyDainton, I have added it now. it is the same as the data file.

Comment: They look the same but they don't act the same. The datafile works on iterations, when you hit the run button, the first iteration picks up _only_ the first object in that datafile array. On the second iteration, it picks up _only_ the second object in that data file array.

Comment: Yes that is what I am hoping for, but as per the screenshot of the runner, it shows it has duplicated it. Now I know that the data file doesn't know which iteration I am wanting. Maybe there is nothing I can do here anyways :/

Comment: I think there is just a misunderstanding of how data files work in the collection runner and you're trying to do something that wouldn't ever work like that.